# Export a gridview with link button to excel

Tags: asp.net, excel, gridview, export

I have a gridview with Link button with Onclick event to open a .pdf file. The file path is generated dynamically under the function in code behind called by the Onclick event in .aspx page. I am able to export it to excel fine. That column comes through as a Hyperlink. But my problem is the Onclick event is not enabled or it did not get exported along with rest of the data to Excel file.

In my GridView (named GVActiveMEOs), I have the set the DataKeyNames as `DataKeyNames="MEO_NR"`. And inside the `asp:TemplateField` I have this `asp:LinkButton`

```
<asp:linkbutton id="lnk" runat="server" onclick="OpenMEO" 
        commandargument='<%# Eval("MEO_NR") %>'
        text='<%# Eval("MEO_NR") %>'>
</asp:linkbutton>
```

Code-Behind

```
Protected Sub OpenMEO(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) 
    Dim strConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("AEM_ESS001_DEVConnectionString").Connect‌​ionString 
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnString) 
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand 
    Dim MPath As String 
    'Dim index As Integer = GVActiveMEOs.SelectedRow.RowIndex 
    'Dim meonum As String = GVActiveMEOs.SelectedDataKey.Value 
    Dim meonum As String = DirectCast(sender, LinkButton).CommandArgument
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text 
    cmd.CommandText = "Select MEOPATH from dbo.udf_GetMEOpath(@myid)" 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myid", meonum) 
    cmd.Connection = con 
    Try 
        con.Open() 
        MPath = cmd.ExecuteScalar() 
        'MsgBox(MPath) 
        ' Dim script As String = "window.open('" & MPath & "', 'Popup', '_newtab');"
        'Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "open", script, True) 
        Response.Redirect(MPath)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Can anyone please give me some help. Rgds, Suma

Comment: please share your markup and code-behind

Comment: My aspx page is as follows:

Comment: <%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="MEO_ACTIVITYRPT.aspx.vb" EnableEventValidation = "false" Inherits="ESSGateKeeper.MEO_ACTIVITYRPT" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">

Comment: <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

Enter Date Range for MEO_ACTIVITY:

Start_Date:<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateStart" runat="server"/>
        End_Date:<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateEnd" runat="server"/>
        <asp:Button ID="srcbtn" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnPDF" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/PDF.jpg" Width="32px" 
Height="32px" onclick="btnPDF_Click"/>
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnExcel" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ExcelImage.jpg" 
onclick="btnExcel_Click" />

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="GVActiveMEOs" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" DataKeyNames="MEO_NR">
        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MEO Number" >
                                             <ItemTemplate>
                                             <asp:linkbutton text='<%# Eval("MEO_NR") %>' runat="server" onclick="OpenMEO" id="lnk" commandargument='<%# Eval("MEO_NR") %>'></asp:linkbutton>

Comment: <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AEMESS001DEVConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * from dbo.udf_ActiveMEOActivity(@in_START, @in_END)">
        <SelectParameters>
            
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtDateStart" Name="in_START" 
                PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtDateEnd" Name="in_END" 
                PropertyName="Text" />
            
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

Comment: and my code behind IS

Comment: Protected Sub OpenMEO(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim strConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("AEM_ESS001_DEVConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim MPath As String
        'Dim index As Integer = GVActiveMEOs.SelectedRow.RowIndex

        'Dim meonum As String = GVActiveMEOs.SelectedDataKey.Value
        Dim meonum As String = DirectCast(sender, LinkButton).CommandArgument

Comment: cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "Select MEOPATH from dbo.udf_GetMEOpath(@myid)"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myid", meonum)
        cmd.Connection = con
        Try
            con.Open()

            MPath = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
            'MsgBox(MPath)
             ' Dim script As String = "window.open('" & MPath & "', 'Popup', '_newtab');"
            'Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "open", script, True)
            Response.Redirect(MPath)

Comment: Sorry for the format. This is my first time using the forum. Thank you in advance, rgds, Suma

Answer (score 0):

Many methods to achieve this.

1.Change `asp:LinkButton` markup and specify `CommandName`

```
<asp:linkbutton id="lnk" runat="server" onclick="OpenMEO" 
        commandargument='<%# Eval("MEO_NR") %>'
        commandname="Select"
        text='<%# Eval("MEO_NR") %>'>
</asp:linkbutton>
```

2.Create a `RowCommandEvent`

Markup

```
OnRowCommand="GVActiveMEOs_OnRowCommand"
```

Code-behind

```
Protected Sub gridview1_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    'custom code
    Dim meonum As String = DirectCast(e.CommandSource, LinkButton).CommandArgument
    'custom code
End Sub
```

Always remember that *clicked row* is not a `SelectedRow` unless you specify the `CommandName` as `CommandName="Select"`

Comment: Hi naveen, Thank you for your time. I am able to open pdf on click in the gridview. My problem is after I export the gridview into excel, the hyperlink functionality is lost!!! It is looking like onclick event is not carried over to excel sheet. appreciate any advice. Rgds, Suma

Comment: When I put my cursor on the link in excel sheet created from export, all I see is : javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$GVActiveMEOs$ctl02$lnk',''). The rowcommand is not executed. Thank you.